# How to sort array by property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array as bellow:

```
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Product 1', color: 'white'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Product 2', color: 'black'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Product 3', color: 'red'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Product 4', color: 'white'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Product 5', color: 'black'},
]
```

I want to sort array based on predefined order by color: red -> white -> black and output:

```
const list = [
  { id: 3, name: 'Product 3', color: 'red'},
  { id: 1, name: 'Product 1', color: 'white'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Product 4', color: 'white'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Product 5', color: 'black'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Product 2', color: 'black'}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let colorPriority = ['red', 'white', 'black'];
list = list.sort((obj1, obj2) => colorPriority.indexOf(obj1.color) - colorPriority.indexOf(obj2.color));
```

this code should work for you.

Comment: Also `list` should be changed from `const` to `let` if OP wants to modify it. Otherwise you'll need a new variable.

Comment: good catch. I'll update the answer.
Thanks